# ASP.NET Load times

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET Project, v3.5 in VB.NET, that I'm working on.  On my home computer pages load pretty much instantaneously when clicking something, but on my work computer (which is a much faster computer) all pages take about one second to load, regardless of the content being generated (like its on a timer or something).  Why is this or how can I go about figuring out why the load time is being delayed on my work computer?

- Both are running ASP.NET v3.5 w/ VB.NET and SQL Server 2008
- Same exact project (copied from on comp to another) with the same exact database
- Debugging is turned on for both
- Home computer is Windows XP Pro, 3GHz Intel, 1.5 Gigs RAM
- Work computer is Windows Vista Home, Core2 Duo 2.40 Ghz, 3 Gigs RAM
- Both running on the ASP.NET Development Server
- Same exact setup except for the computer itself

Thanks for your input.

*SOLVED* - The issue was the IPv6 issue with FireFox.  I turned it off and everythings grand now.  Thanks everyone for your input, definitely good advise for tracking down more serious performance issues, which will come in handy later, just not for this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Pinged the database-server from the two PCs?

Comment: You said that the database is the same but where is the database sever physically? Is it at home or at work? How are you access the DB Server from either place? 

Also, is there extensive DB Usage?  Could the databases be busy when you are at work because it is during the day, where at home the time might be out of business hours?

Comment: In both cases the database server is local to that computer, and I'm the only one using it, for only this project.  The data in both is exactly the same.  I just made a backup and copied everything from one to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Firefox, it could be related to [this issue with IPv6 support in FF](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/07/speeding-up-communication-between-firefox-and-visual-studios-built-in-web-server/).

Comment: In which case... turn off IPv6 in Vista.

Comment: that definitely sounds like it could be the issue!

Comment: that was it exactly!  Thanks a lot... that had been bugging me.  Now I can happily continue developing w/out a 1 second delay everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

Is the SQL Server local in both cases?

One thing you could do would be to run a Trace to see where the delays (if any) are within the actual ASP.NET process...

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <trace enabled ="true" pageOutput ="false" requestLimit ="20" traceMode ="SortByTime " />        
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do to investigate performance problems/differences:

1. You mention the 'same exact database'.  If it is a local database at home and you are hitting your home database from your work machine, that may account for the latency.
2. Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for measuring web traffic.  This can help determine if it is a server or client issue.
3. Use [Firebug with Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/).  Look at the NET tab and/or the javascript profiling on the Console tab to determine whether it is a javascript issue, or a server issue.
4. Turn on ASP.NET tracing in your web.config to check timings in your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Where I work we have firewall issues connecting to crl.microsoft.com.

Trying adding this to your hosts file:

127.0.0.1    crl.microsoft.com

Then restart IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebug slows down the loading of web pages, especially CSS rendering. Try disabling Firebug to see if that fixes your problem.